# calculator problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator for my ipad.
I have set up 3 buttons so far and one textfield.
each button presents a number, 1 until 3.

```
- (IBAction)OnePressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *currentText = FIELD1.text;
    FIELD1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", currentText, @"1"];

}
- (IBAction)twoPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *currentText = FIELD1.text;

    FIELD1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", currentText, @"2"];
}
- (IBAction)ThreePressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *currentText = FIELD1.text;

    FIELD1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", currentText, @"3"];
}
```

When I press button 1 in works fine, when I press button 2 afterwards, it said 112 instead of 12.

Any help with this problem is appreciated.

EDIT: Oops, found the error, the code was fine, i accidently linked up the action with 2 buttons.
Silly mistake, thanks for thinking along with me though.

Comment: Can you print `currentText` in `twoPressed` before you modify it? What is it at that point?

Comment: i dont really know what you mean by printing currentText in twoPressed..

Comment: Please look up NSLog();

Comment: you would have an easier time using an `NSMatrix` of buttons. does something like that exist on iOS?

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into the question, please post it as an answer and mark it accepted. It will help people know that this issue has been resolved in the future.

Comment: ... or just delete the question.